# $f\sim g\implies \ln f\sim \ln g$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ such that $$\lim_{+\infty }f=\lim_{+\infty }g=+\infty $$
and with the property that $f\sim g$ at $+\infty $. Show that $\ln(f)\sim \ln(g)$.

In my course it's written that $$\ln(f(x))-\ln(g(x))=\ln\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)\overset{f\sim g}{\underset{x\to +\infty }{\longrightarrow}} \ln(1)=0.$$
I don't understand why this argument is enough. To me we have to show that 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{\ln(f(x))-\ln(g(x))}{\ln(g(x))}=0,$$
and I don't understand in what the fact that $$\lim_{x\to \infty }\ln(f(x))-\ln(g(x))=0\implies \lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{\ln(f(x))-\ln(g(x))}{\ln(g(x))}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Observe $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \ln g(x) = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $g\to \infty$, $g$ and $\ln g$ are both non-zero for $x$ large enough.
$$\begin{align} \frac{\ln f(x) }{\ln g(x)}
&= \frac{\ln\left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)\right) }{\ln g(x)}\\
&=1 + \underbrace{\frac{1}{\ln g(x)}}_{\to 0}\underbrace{\ln\left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)}_{\to 0}
\end{align}
$$

Hence $\ln f \sim \ln g$